# unable to use ignore_class in SparseCategoricalCrossentropy

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

I was training a tensorflow model and using `ignore_class=0` to ignore the class 0 when computing the loss.

```
unet.compile(
        loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
            from_logits=True,
            ignore_class=0,
        ),
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
        metrics=["accuracy"],
    )
```

This stopped working after I updated all my packages including python version, tf and keras.
Running the model now raises the following error:

```
model.fit(
  File "/user/anaconda3/envs/environment/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 122, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/user/anaconda3/envs/environment/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/nn.py", line 623, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Arguments `target` and `output` must have the same shape up until the last dimension: target.shape=(None, 224, 224, 1), output.shape=(None, 224, 224, 224, 6)
```

The training is successful when I comment out `ignore_class=0`. Any clue what's causing the extra 224 in output.shape?

```
    unet = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=out)
```

This is what I get when I log the shapes of my inputs and outputs.

```
inputs <KerasTensor shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32, sparse=None, name=keras_tensor_429> (None, 224, 224, 3)
out <KerasTensor shape=(None, 224, 224, 6), dtype=float32, sparse=False, name=keras_tensor_459> (None, 224, 224, 6)
```

Here's my model architecture

```
def model(num_classes):
    base = keras.applications.DenseNet121(
        input_shape=(224, 224, 3), include_top=False, weights="imagenet"
    )

    base.summary()

    skip_names = [
        "conv1_relu",  # size 64*64
        "pool2_relu",  # size 32*32
        "pool3_relu",  # size 16*16
        "pool4_relu",  # size 8*8
        "relu",  # size 4*4
    ]

    # output of these layers
    skip_outputs = [base.get_layer(name).output for name in skip_names]
        
    # Building the downstack with the above layers. We use the pre-trained model as such, without any fine-tuning.
    downstack = keras.Model(inputs=base.input, outputs=skip_outputs)
    # freeze the downstack layers
    downstack.trainable = False

    upstack = [
        # pix2pix.upsample(1024, 3),
        pix2pix.upsample(512, 3),
        pix2pix.upsample(256, 3),
        pix2pix.upsample(128, 3),
        pix2pix.upsample(64, 3),
    ]

    # define the input layer
    inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=[224, 224, 3])

    # downsample
    down = downstack(inputs)
    out = down[-1]

    # prepare skip-connections
    skips = reversed(down[:-1])
    # choose the last layer at first 4 --> 8

    # upsample with skip-connections
    for up, skip in zip(upstack, skips):
        out = up(out)
        out = keras.layers.Concatenate()([out, skip])

    # define the final transpose conv layer
    out = keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
        num_classes,
        3,
        strides=2,
        padding="same",
    )(out)

    # complete unet model
    unet = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=out)

    unet.compile(
        loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
            from_logits=True,
            # ignore_class=0,
        ),
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
        metrics=["accuracy"],
    )
    unet.summary()

    return unet
```

Comment: Could you provide the versions of the main packages (TF and Keras) before and after your update?